# Junk a part of the directory with unzip?

Tags: zip

A zipfile `f.zip` contains a bunch of files all with directories.

```
 A/B
 A/B/C
 A/B/C/D

 ..
 A/B/C/D/and/some/more/dirs
 A/B2
```

Now I'm only interested in the tree below C/D. I can do `unzip f.zip */D/* -d .` which unzips everything under D - assuming that D is a unique sequence - to the current directory including A/B/C, however I want D to be the root of my unzip action. Of course I can just move D to my current working dir but I consider that cheating.

Man pages nor google did reveal a solution, but maybe I'm overlooking and maybe there's a nicer solution than moving..

Oh my platform is mac os x 10.8.prettyup2date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the unzip man page:

```
   -j     junk paths.  The archive's directory structure is not recreated;
     all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default,
     the current one).
```

So:

```
unzip -d D -j f.zip */D/*
```

Extract it all to a folder called D, but without directory structure (note this will extract files in subdirectories of D into the top-level output D folder).

**EDIT** OP wanted to keep file structure UNDER the D folder.

```
unzip -l f.zip | grep 'A/B/C/D' | \
perl -ple 's/\s+\d+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}\s+(.*)$/$1/' | \
while read file
do 
    unzip -j -d "$(echo $file | sed 's:A/B/C/\(.*\)/.*:\1:g')" f.zip "$file"
done
```

Each step in parts:

```
unzip -l f.zip
```

get a list of files in f.zip

```
grep 'A/B/C/D'
```

grep out the lines that show files under the target directory

```
perl -ple 's/\s+\d+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}\s+(.*)$/$1/'
```

use perl to get the file name on that matching line (my sed-fu is not as great as Stephane's, so I'll use perl!), *NOTE this handles spaces in file names* :)

```
while read file
do
```

loop through the files produced from the above commands and assign it to `$file`

```
unzip -j -d "$(echo $file | sed 's:A/B/C/\(.*\)/.*:\1:g')" f.zip "$file"
```

unzip the target `$file`, junking its path, to the destination directory got from

```
echo $file | sed 's:A/B/C/\(.*\)/.*:\1:g'
```

which removes the leading A/B/C/ path from the filename, note it's wrapped in $() (a `Command substitution`, see bash for more details) and that command substitution is inside double quotes to preserve spaces (and actually evaluate the `$()`).

```
done
```

completes the loop.

This in effect runs an unzip operation for each file matched under A/B/C:

```
unzip -j -d "D" f.zip "A/B/C/D/"
unzip -j -d "D" f.zip "A/B/C/D/b"
unzip -j -d "D" f.zip "A/B/C/D/e"
unzip -j -d "D/stupid space" f.zip "A/B/C/D/stupid space/"
unzip -j -d "D/stupid space" f.zip "A/B/C/D/stupid space/b"
unzip -j -d "D/stupid space" f.zip "A/B/C/D/stupid space/e"
unzip -j -d "D/stupid space" f.zip "A/B/C/D/stupid space/d"
unzip -j -d "D/stupid space" f.zip "A/B/C/D/stupid space/c"
unzip -j -d "D/stupid space" f.zip "A/B/C/D/stupid space/a"
unzip -j -d "D" f.zip "A/B/C/D/d"
unzip -j -d "D" f.zip "A/B/C/D/f"
```

If you run this command to extract into an already existing file structure you will need to add an additional `-o` to `override` existing files (or the first unzip operation that would clobber a file would prompt with a `replace D/b? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  extracting: D/b` and then bomb out). If you need that prompting, then you'll have to use another method of looping that doesn't use read and *also* handles spaces (`for $( ... )` will fail that test). I'll leave that as an exercise for you to work out if you need to do that!

Comment: Well actually there are a lot more subdirectories under D. So I want only to `junk` the directories up to D. will update question.

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome and awful at the same time. It's a good lesson in piping, perl, sed and bash scripting in general. But I'm not convinced it's 'nicer' than moving and removing. It would have been nice if the -j flag accepted a string for junking a partial directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

Mount the zip as a directory. You can do this through [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), a generic framework for filesystem drivers implemented by ordinary programs rather than kernel drivers. Install [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io/) (generic FUSE support on OSX), then [fuse-zip](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) (a FUSE driver for zip archives). Once you've installed the necessary software, mount the archive:

```
mkdir /tmp/myzip
fuse-zip f.zip /tmp/myzip
```

You can now access the files in the zip as if it was a directory. To extract `A/B/C/D`, copy it:

```
cp -Rp /tmp/myzip/A/B/C/D /some/where
```

Unmount the zip when you're done with it.

```
fusermount -u /tmp/myzip
rmdir /tmp/myzip
```

If you want to skip with software that's preinstalled, I think you do have to unzip `A/B/C/D` and then move the directory.